# SeleniumError in vba

Tags: vba, selenium

I am trying to take a Selenium test and convert it into excel VBA code.

I have come to a Selenium error when I have tried to do my code [I am pretty much useless here:( ]

Could I get guidance on the vba error?

Secondly any suggestions on how to do the vba code

The error is as attached [VBA Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHG3m.png)

The vba code that I have at the moment is

```html
Sub Buy()

    Dim driver As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    Dim count As Long
    
    Sheets("Input").Activate

    Set driver = CreateObject("Selenium.ChromeDriver")
    count = 1
    
    ' Code assumes all VAT numbers in Column A are valid
    ' No error checking is included here in case they are not
    '
    While (Len(Range("A" & count)) > 0)
    
        driver.Get "https://www.mycode.com.au/Portfolio/Details/12635600"
        
    driver.FindElementById("New Buy").Click
    driver.FindElementById("New Buy").Click
    driver.FindElement(By.ID("SecurityCode")).SendKeys ("JBH")
    driver.FindElement(By.ID("NumberOfShares")).SendKeys ("500")
    driver.FindElement(By.ID("SharePrice")).SendKeys ("20")
    driver.FindElement(By.ID("Fees")).SendKeys ("9.5")
    driver.FindElement(By.ID("Submit")).Click
        
        ' Uncomment the next line if you need to introduce a delay in the browser
        ' to allow it to load the results page
        'Driver.Wait 1000
        
        Range("B" & count) = driver.FindElementByXPath("//table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]").Text
        
        count = count + 1
    
    Wend
    
    driver.Quit
        
End Sub
```

The Selenium IDE file that I am trying to emulate is

```html
{
  "id": "d4a3caeb-1fd0-4a30-8c17-d69d7a1b6e36",
  "version": "2.0",
  "name": "Test 10",
  "url": "https://www.mycode.com.au",
  "tests": [{
    "id": "880b98ad-ce57-416d-abab-d5b9eac336cf",
    "name": "Test 10",
    "commands": [{
      "id": "9c84d13e-49f7-4e1e-8e6b-45a1b9654a87",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "open",
      "target": "/Portfolio/Details/126356",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "57eb50bf-f996-4e20-b9c2-15f476e43324",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "setWindowSize",
      "target": "1552x840",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "b627d6f1-2d7a-4b92-bdf6-80c400f787e5",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "click",
      "target": "linkText=New Buy",
      "targets": [
        ["linkText=New Buy", "linkText"],
        ["css=.btn-order-buy", "css:finder"],
        ["xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'New Buy')])[2]", "xpath:link"],
        ["xpath=//a[@onclick='return false;']", "xpath:attributes"],
        ["xpath=//div[@id='active-tab']/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/a", "xpath:idRelative"],
        ["xpath=(//a[contains(@href, '/PortfolioTransaction/NewBuy?portfolioId=12635600')])[3]", "xpath:href"],
        ["xpath=//div[2]/div/div/div/div/a", "xpath:position"]
      ],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "f4d72730-3eaa-44e7-85c3-1c63a79032bc",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "type",
      "target": "css=div:nth-child(3) > #SecurityCode",
      "targets": [
        ["css=div:nth-child(3) > #SecurityCode", "css:finder"],
        ["xpath=(//input[@id='SecurityCode'])[4]", "xpath:attributes"],
        ["xpath=//div[@id='page-trade-details']/div/fieldset/div/div[3]/input", "xpath:idRelative"],
        ["xpath=//fieldset/div/div[3]/input", "xpath:position"]
      ],
      "value": "JBH"
    }, {
      "id": "2a6976b9-7364-4dab-bbaf-ebdc214cbe2c",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "type",
      "target": "id=NumberOfShares",
      "targets": [
        ["id=NumberOfShares", "id"],
        ["name=NumberOfShares", "name"],
        ["css=#NumberOfShares", "css:finder"],
        ["xpath=//input[@id='NumberOfShares']", "xpath:attributes"],
        ["xpath=//div[@id='page-trade-details']/div/fieldset/div/div[4]/div[2]/input", "xpath:idRelative"],
        ["xpath=//div[4]/div[2]/input", "xpath:position"]
      ],
      "value": "500"
    }, {
      "id": "1bdbb4a4-221c-4e5f-87d7-3a6e0c9e3ad4",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "type",
      "target": "id=SharePrice",
      "targets": [
        ["id=SharePrice", "id"],
        ["name=SharePrice", "name"],
        ["css=#SharePrice", "css:finder"],
        ["xpath=//input[@id='SharePrice']", "xpath:attributes"],
        ["xpath=//div[@id='page-trade-details']/div/fieldset/div/div[4]/div[3]/input", "xpath:idRelative"],
        ["xpath=//div[4]/div[3]/input", "xpath:position"]
      ],
      "value": "20"
    }, {
      "id": "e8a85e6f-30bc-4a9f-a13e-bc591ac24d0b",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "type",
      "target": "id=Fees",
      "targets": [
        ["id=Fees", "id"],
        ["name=Fees", "name"],
        ["css=#Fees", "css:finder"],
        ["xpath=//input[@id='Fees']", "xpath:attributes"],
        ["xpath=//div[@id='page-trade-details']/div/fieldset/div/div[4]/div[4]/input", "xpath:idRelative"],
        ["xpath=//div[4]/div[4]/input", "xpath:position"]
      ],
      "value": "9.5"
    }, {
      "id": "3bbf2177-6e3e-4fa1-a00b-f5eff9ffe553",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "click",
      "target": "css=#page-trade-details #Submit",
      "targets": [
        ["css=#page-trade-details #Submit", "css:finder"],
        ["xpath=(//input[@id='Submit'])[3]", "xpath:attributes"],
        ["xpath=//div[@id='page-trade-details']/div[2]/input[2]", "xpath:idRelative"],
        ["xpath=//div[2]/form/div/div[2]/input[2]", "xpath:position"]
      ],
      "value": ""
    }]
  }],
  "suites": [{
    "id": "03623809-e8f4-4f37-a9dc-548b1aba1757",
    "name": "Default Suite",
    "persistSession": false,
    "parallel": false,
    "timeout": 300,
    "tests": ["880b98ad-ce57-416d-abab-d5b9eac336cf"]
  }],
  "urls": ["https://www.mycode.com.au/"],
  "plugins": []
}
```

Comment: Seelnium IDE IIRC allows you to output in different languages. Output as python or possibly .Net (if available) and translate from there. You are mixing languages in the above.  You set up selenium to auto-instantiate but then SET the driver reference with late-binding. You don't change the VAT # in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.

Firstly, "mixing languages" - can you please be more specific

Secondly "You set up selenium to auto-instantiate but then SET the driver reference with late-binding." - again can you be more specific

My apologies, but my skill level is way off. This is a stand alone project, for myself, to achieve an efficiency outcome re data entry into a webform.

The reference to VAT can be ignored. The code is extracted from a website to give me a start on the vba. VAT is not relevant to my task.

I have  sent the output to python as follows

```
# Generated by Selenium IDE
import pytest
import time
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

class TestTest10():
  def setup_method(self, method):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    self.vars = {}
  
  def teardown_method(self, method):
    self.driver.quit()
  
  def test_test10(self):
    self.driver.get("https://www.mywebsite.com.au/Portfolio/Details/12635600")
    self.driver.set_window_size(1552, 840)
    self.driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "New Buy").click()
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div:nth-child(3) > #SecurityCode").send_keys("JBH")
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "NumberOfShares").send_keys("500")
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "SharePrice").send_keys("20")
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "Fees").send_keys("9.5")
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#page-trade-details #Submit").click()
```

With this I have modified my vba code as follows:

```
Sub Buy()

    Dim driver As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    Dim count As Long
    
    Sheets("Input").Activate

    Set driver = CreateObject("Selenium.ChromeDriver")
    count = 1
    

    While (Len(Range("A" & count)) > 0)
    
    driver.Get "https://www.mywebsite.com.au/Portfolio/Details/12635600"
        
    driver.FindElement(By.LINK_TEXT, ("New Buy")).Click
    driver.FindElement(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div:nth-child(3) > #SecurityCode").SendKeys ("JBH")
    driver.FindElement(By.ID("NumberOfShares")).SendKeys ("500")
    driver.FindElement(By.ID("SharePrice")).SendKeys ("20")
    driver.FindElement(By.ID("Fees")).SendKeys ("9.5")
    driver.FindElement(By.ID("Submit")).Click
        
               
        Range("B" & count) = driver.FindElementByXPath("//table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]").Text
        
        count = count + 1
    
    Wend
    
    driver.Quit
        
End Sub
```

On running the vba I get a "Run-time error ‘424’ Object Required". I am unable to work out how to overcome this error.